# What are the reasons that ADB and Android studio stop recognising a device

Tags: android, android-studio, adb, nexus-5

A few times a day my device disappears from the adb devices list.

Running: adb devices from the command line just says `List of devices attached` with no devices and no device is visible in run dialog of Android Studio.

I'm using the latest version of the Android SDK with a Nexus 5 (Lollipop 5.0.1) on Windows 8.1 but I have the same problem with a Samsung Galaxy S2.

It will work for a few hours but then I will get a log entry "device disconnected" and the device disappears. The device is still visible in Windows explorer and the `USB debugging connected` notification is still shown on the device.

Running `adb kill-server` doesn't fix the problem.

Disconnecting and re-connecting the device usually fixes the problem but sometimes I need to restart the device.

Has anyone experienced this or have ideas of how to debug it?

Answer (score 1):

One of the debug methods apart from adb kill server, reboot device or pc is to scan for hardware changes.

MyComputer properties -> Device Manager->

Right click on PC-Name scan for hardware changes. Of course the device must be connected while doing this

This saved me quite a few times.